# Is OData only for Javascripts in Dynamics CRM 13/15/16 ?

Tags: odata, dynamics-crm-2015

Is **OData** only for **Javascript**s in *Dynamics CRM 13/15/16* ?

Comment: May be you are confused with OrganizationDATA service & OpenDATA protocol, but James explanation is crystal clear..

Comment: It was first made available in CRM 2011 I believe.  (not sure if you are trying to see how far back it goes or if it is in the most current version).

Answer (score 2):

Depends. You can use OData in a variety of languages.

CRM provides two OData based services, check out [Use Microsoft Dynamics 365 web services](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/mt608128.aspx).

**Web API**

> The Web API is new for Microsoft Dynamics 365 (online & on-premises)
>   and will provide parity with the Organization service. Compared to the
>   Organization service, the Web API provides better compatibility across
>   a wide variety of programming languages, platforms, and devices. The
>   Web API implements the OData (Open Data Protocol) v4.

The web api is new, and can be easily used outside of CRM in multiple languages and platforms.

**Organization Data service**

> The Organization Data service, also sometimes known as the “OData” or
>   “REST” endpoint has also been available since Microsoft Dynamics CRM
>   2011. This service implemented the OData v2 standard. While this service will continue to be available as-is for years to come, we are
>   deprecating it with Microsoft Dynamics 365.

The organization data service is old (and deprecated), this was harder to use outside of CRM. Most of the time people used JavaScript to access it from within CRM.